# AEM Search and Promote search refinement

Tags: java, search, adobe, aem

If I integrate S&P with AEM and use the built in components, is it possible to do search refinement for specific sections of the JCR?

For instance if I have a forum built from community components with user generated content. Can I add a S&P search box which will only search this forum?

Comment: Have you tried [Tagging of user generated content](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/author/communities/tagcloud.html) and [communities search](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/author/communities/search.html) In **Search** component there is a feature for configuring Search Paths Under the Search Settings tab, to specify how what paths are to search when a query is entered by a visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S&P is external SAAS for AEM and S&P can not search in your local JCR repository. You have to create/feed database on the S&P side for the search.

You are collecting data that you want to be searched and pushing this data to S&P. Each part of this data should contains also information of repository path where this data located.

> E.g. {'first', 'product', 'any'}<->/content/site/firstProduct
>
> Later any search request to S&P for `first` will returns also path `/content/site/firstProduct`

Back to your question:
you can push S&P any data from you JCR repository. If you pushed `only ... this forum` data  then `a S&P search box which will only search this forum`

Comment: How do I push to S&P? I was under the impression it crawled my site to get the data. How is dynamically created content handled?

Comment: It is two variants of S&P usage let you content to be crawled or feed S&P by your data. Generally S&P crawler is very flexible. https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/snp/c_about_url_masks.html
If you are using crawler you can mask your forum with all generated content like http://your.domain.com/forum/*.html